# POST request with file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Wanted to call Post method on my existing API which is working fine with PostMan, but now I wanted to pass the body content as the file type.

Current, when I added the headers in the request.post it throw me 400 bad request exception but when I remove the headers it gives me 415 Media type which I am not able to understand, Could anyone please help me on this.

My working code is mentioned here:

```
import os
import logging
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

config_directory = 'my-laptp-location\where-i-have\all-mt-files'
url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/update'
usr = 'user'
passwd = 'pass'

for fileName in os.listdir(config_directory):
    print('Processing file: ', fileName)
    headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}

    abs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(config_directory, fileName))

    # files = {'file': (abs_path, open(abs_path, 'rb'), 'application/json', {'Expires': '0'})}
    # I tried the above as well but It also throw media type exception
    with open(abs_path, 'rb') as f:
        r = requests.post(calling_url, files={abs_path: f}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(usr,passwd),headers=headers)
        print(r.status_code)
```

My file, if I do the vi abs_path:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
}
```

It is nothing but just plain JSON not array no nesting.

Comment: are you passing the right `'Accept'` to your headers?

Comment: The `Content-Type` headers needs to be `multipart/form-data` for file uploads

Comment: You should be using an `r` type literal for `config_directory`, i.e.: `config_directory = r'my-laptp-location\where-i-have\all-mt-files'` because `\a` is '\x07' (alarm) and not backslash followed by 'a'.

Comment: I tried with both the comment remove the Accept from headers and added multipart/form-data as suggest by @RishiDev but still having 415 as unsupported Media Type, I have updated my input file

Comment: I have tried everything on the internet but nothing is working as expected - in the end it says that "unsupported Media type" 415. not sure from here what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Below code is worked on me, really I am not 100% sure why this was not working before I have tried everything as well, I might have missed something which still I am not understood completely.

Hope this might help few, in future.

```
import os
import logging
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

config_directory = 'my-laptp-location\where-i-have\all-mt-files'
url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/update'
usr = 'user'
passwd = 'pass'

for fileName in os.listdir(config_directory):
    print('Processing file: ', fileName)
    headers={'Content-type':'application/json'}

    abs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(config_directory, fileName))

    with open(abs_path, 'rb') as f:
        r = requests.post(calling_url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(usr, passwd), data=f)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.content)
```